# Get a list of mocha `describe` calls for a given test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js

Is there a way to get an array of messages passed to `describe`?

I would like to dynamically create the `testList` array from the values passed as messages in the `describe` calls below.

Example Test

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chai/3.5.0/chai.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mocha/2.5.3/mocha.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mocha/2.5.3/mocha.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="mocha"></div>
<script>
    mocha.setup('bdd');
</script>
<script>
    mocha.checkLeaks();
    //mocha.globals(['jQuery']);
</script>
<script>
    var expect = chai.expect;
    var testList = ['methodTrue', 'methodFalse', 'methodIdentity'];
    var testObject = {
        methodTrue: function () {return true;},
        methodFalse: function () {return false;},
        methodIdentity: function (n) {return n;}
    }
    describe('testObject', function () {
        describe('methodTrue', function () {
            it('should be a method', function () {
                expect(testObject.methodTrue).to.be.a('function');
            });
        });
        describe('methodFalse', function () {
            it('should be a method', function () {
                expect(testObject.methodFalse).to.be.a('function');
            });
        });
        describe('methodIdentity', function () {
            it('should be a method', function () {
                expect(testObject.methodIdentity).to.be.a('function');
            });
        });
        it('should have a method for every test', function () {
            Object.keys(testObject).forEach(function (v, i) {
                expect(testList.indexOf(v), 'no test for ' + v).to.be.above(-1);  
            });
        });
    });
    mocha.run();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably look at the source of Mocha and figure how to walk a test suite. However, here's a way to do it that does not depend on knowing the internals and won't break if the internals change. The strategy is to replace `describe` with your own function, which records what is passed to it so you can use it later. I've used Mocha at the command line but there's no difference between doing this in a suite meant to be run in Node vs one meant to be run in a browser.

```
var blocks = [];

function wrapperDescribe() {
    // It is generally unsafe to just leak `arguments` objects. So we
    // slice it to make a copy before pushing it into `blocks`.
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    blocks.push(args);
    describe.apply(this, args);
}

(function () {
    // We do not do this at the top level because it would modify a
    // global used by all Mocha files. Whether or not you do want this
    // depends on the needs to you project.
    var describe = wrapperDescribe;

    function fn () {}

    describe("one", function () {
        it("test 1", fn);
        it("test 2", fn);
    });

    describe("two", function () {
        it("test 1", fn);
        it("test 2", fn);
    });
}());

console.log(blocks);
```

The output:

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/mocha 
[ [ 'one', [Function] ], [ 'two', [Function] ] ]


  one
    ✓ test 1
    ✓ test 2

  two
    ✓ test 1
    ✓ test 2


  4 passing (6ms)
```

The array is output before the tests are run, which is normal for Mocha. (Mocha first reads all tests, executes all `describe` callbacks, and then runs the tests.)

To get this to work only on a subset of `describe` blocks, you could just not override `describe` but rather call `wrapperDescribe` directly as needed.